# How to pass custom authorizer info to step function input?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I have step function which is invoked by API gateway with custom authorizer.
I know how to pass custom authorizer information to lambda function from API gateway as below.

```
def registerEmail(event, context):
    authInfo=event.requestContext.authorizer;
```

I want to pass this custom authorizer information to lambda inside the step functions but could not find useful information.
Could anyone tell me how to solve this?